# d3 extracting a single value from a csv file

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I have a CSV file like this (a simplified version of a much larger file):

```
year,state,value
2012,Alabama,12
2012,New York,17
2012,Iowa,16
2012,Oregon,10
2012,Montana,14
```

I want to extract the value from a state like Iowa. I have a function which gives me an object.

```
var t= data.filter(function(d) { return d.state == "Iowa" });
```

How do I extract the value ("16") from this array? Thanks.

Comment: No it's not in a key. But I got the answer below. Thanks for your interest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data array probably looks like this.

```
var data = [{"year": "2012", "state": "Alabama", "value": "12"}, 
     {"year": "2012", "state": "New York", "value": "17"}, 
     {"year": "2012", "state": "Iowa", "value": "16"}, 
     {"year": "2012", "state": "Oregon", "value": "10"}, 
     {"year": "2012", "state": "Montana", "value": "10"}];
```

To extract the value, you would do this

```
data.filter(function(d) { return d.state === "Iowa" })[0].value;
```

```js
var data = [{"year": "2012", "state": "Alabama", "value": "12"}, 
     {"year": "2012", "state": "New York", "value": "17"}, 
     {"year": "2012", "state": "Iowa", "value": "16"}, 
     {"year": "2012", "state": "Oregon", "value": "10"}, 
     {"year": "2012", "state": "Montana", "value": "10"}];

var value = data.filter(function(d) { return d.state === "Iowa" })[0].value;

document.getElementById("my-val").innerHTML = value;
```

```html
<p id="my-val"></p>
```

You had the right idea. The `filter` function returns a new array, in this case the element is an object. To access this element, use bracket notation and then get the `value` property.

Comment: That did it! Thanks. I knew it was probably something simple